# Changing from AfxGetAppModuleState to AfxGetStaticModuleState gives linker error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c++, mfc, linker-errors

I have a dll module that has a property "Use MFC in a Shared DLL". I expected that at the start of all the public methods that can be called from outside should have

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
```

But in code, I found them to have

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetAppModuleState());
```

Currently we are facing some application crash and with access violation. I was suspecting this could be one possibility and so I tried to change in one of the method to call AfxGetStaticModuleState instead of AfxGetAppModuleState.
I started to get the linker error

```
LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I dont understand why this error comes up with this change!
Please help

Adding call stack:

```
    1b0b2ce1()  
msvbvm60.dll!7299ce49()     
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for msvbvm60.dll]  
msvbvm60.dll!7299f97d()     
user32.dll!764bc4e7()   
user32.dll!764bc5e7()   
user32.dll!764bc590()   
user32.dll!764b4f0e()   
user32.dll!764afe58()   
user32.dll!764b4f7d()   
ntdll.dll!777a702e()    
user32.dll!764b4ec3()   
user32.dll!764ab300()   
msvbvm60.dll!7295f45a()     
msvbvm60.dll!7295f9bd()     
msvbvm60.dll!72941b31()     
ntdll.dll!777b89d8()    
ntdll.dll!7778f731()    
ntdll.dll!777a60b4()    
ntdll.dll!7778f632()    
msvcr110d.dll!_endthreadex(unsigned int retcode)  Line 410  C
mfc110d.dll!AfxEndThread(unsigned int nExitCode, int bDelete)  Line 388 + 0xc bytes C++
mfc110d.dll!_AfxThreadEntry(void * pParam)  Line 129    C++
msvcr110d.dll!_callthreadstartex()  Line 354 + 0xf bytes    C
msvcr110d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd)  Line 337  C
kernel32.dll!7621ed6c()     
ntdll.dll!777c37eb()    
ntdll.dll!777c37be()
```

Comment: Give us more information about the contents of the callstack and the crash location.

Comment: As you can see: There is no DLL code from you involved. Even there is no code from you executed. OK. It might be a chance that you destroy the stack in a very harsh way. But even than you should be able to debug it. So if there is a bug, you destroy the stack or the heap in some way. So there is no direct "codeing error" that causes the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was mainly with the linker error than AfxGetAppModuleState or AfxGetStaticModuleState itself. Sorry if there was any confusion in the question I asked.
This linker error occurs when the symbol is defined in another module which this module refers or the order of the header files with MFC and non MFC are declared.
It was a tough time for me to solve this by organizing the header. I had to park this task aside so that I can pick this again in free time!

Answer (score 0):

About the linker error: For a DLL AfxGetAppModuleState is wrong.

Please read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj129660(v=vs.100).aspx

> This swaps the current module state with the state returned from
>   AfxGetAppModuleState until the end of the current scope.
>
> To set or restore the module state from a DLL function, do not use
>   AfxGetAppModuleState. Instead, use AfxGetStaticModuleState.
>
> For more information on module states and MFC, see Managing the State
>   Data of MFC Modules in Creating New Documents, Windows, and Views and
>   Technical Note 58.

I can tell you nothing about the crash reason as long as you don't give us more information about the callstack and crash location.

Comment: Hi had linking problems using `AfxGetStaticModuleState` in a DLL and when I replaced them by `AfxGetAppModuleState` they just went away. https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/161/Q161589/